# How do I show, that the projection of $\vec{a}$ is spanned subspace which is through matrix $A=\vec{a}\vec{a}^T$ described?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\vec{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a normed vector.

Thanks for +1. Problem is I don't know how to start.

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to start.

Comment: @AlenaEverdeen I think the problem is the way you pose your question. Did you understand the question well ? ME NO !
So if yes, please edit what you wrote above to make the context clear for us.

Comment: @AlenaEverdeen You may not know where to start, but you must have thoughts on the question. What do you know about the problem? What do you need to know in order to solve it? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you purchase a projector from your local electronics store.

Then draw an $\vec a$ on the wall of your home.  Bedroom wall should be fine.

Now, plug in your new projector, turn it on, and point it towards the $\vec a$.

You have now shown that the projection of $\vec a$ is spanned subspace which is through matrix A.

Comment: This is genius.